# É possível listar todos os bairros de uma cidade?

Tags: google-maps

Estou usando a API do Google-Maps, porém não encontrei em lugar a algum da documentação algo referente, eu gostaria de listar todos os bairros de uma cidade especifica, porém os itens com bairro (neighborhood) só aparecem se eu digitar uma rua (em alguns casos tem que ter a rua e um numero de residencia) para que os bairros esteja disponíveis.

Por exemplo:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua%20Cascavel,%20Curitiba%20-%20Paraná
```

Me retorna o bairro:

```
{
   "long_name" : "Boqueirão",
   "short_name" : "Boqueirão",
   "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
}
```

Mas desta forma:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Rua%20Cascavel,%20Curitiba%20-%20Paraná
```

Me retorna apenas o `locality`, `administrative_area_level_2`, `administrative_area_level_1` e `country`

É possível retornar todos bairros de uma cidade especifica? Se não for possível existe alguma alternativa?

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se a gente vai acabar repetindo uma discussão que já aconteceu [por aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/4337) a respeito de *CEPs*, mas o que penso e já tive experiências para esse caso dos bairros é que seja improvável encontrar algo atualizado e de graça pela internet. Provavelmente com a [base de dados dos *Correios*](http://shopping.correios.com.br/wbm/store/script/wbm2400902p01.aspx?cd_company=ErZW8Dm9i54=&cd_department=SsNp3FlaUpM=) é possível obter todos os bairros de uma cidade, mas tem aquela questão do alto custo.

A alternativa do *Google Maps* também acho inviável, tanto pelo valor de uso empresarial e também pela forma gratuita, já que pelos [termos de serviço](https://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html) do *Google Maps* é proibido o download de informações em massa de qualquer conteúdo (até porque tem aquele limite de 2500 requisições), para o caso de fazer algum tipo de serviço para obter todos eles.

Qualquer informação de logradouro, até mesmo cidades é bem inconstante, cada dia deve surgir algo novo no Brasil, o que acaba necessitando uma atualização diária destas informações, e por sua vez invalidando muitas outras fontes que encontramos por aí.

Esta [base de dados em MySQL](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3s4109959l985ea/CEPs_remodelado.rar) com as tabelas `bairros`, `cidades` e `logradouros` talvez seria a alternativa "*offline*" pra você, mas é um arquivo de 2011 e não sei se as informações são ainda mais antigas.

<sup>**Nota:** Para conhecimento, a quantidade de registros nesta base *MySQL*: 28.883 bairros, 9.968 cidades e 563.825 logradouros.</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, infelizmente o meu problema é que muitos webservices (pareceiros) que a empresa usa trabalha com os nomes conforme o GoogleMaps e não disponibilizam está lista de bairros/endereços publicamente :(